# NLog using When Condition Renderer for value availability

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have a value for log input (`event-properties:item=Id`) but that value could be empty sometimes. I'd like NLog to generate a value (`guid`) if it's null/empty. I'm trying this When Condition Renderer but I haven't been able to make it generate anything, the input value is still empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
<parameter name="Id" type="System.Guid" 
layout="${when:when=length('${event-properties:item=Id}')>0:${event-properties\:item=Id}:${guid\:format=N}}"/>
```

Using NLog 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
<parameter name="Id" type="System.Guid" layout="${event-properties:Id:whenEmpty=${guid:format=N}}" />
```

Btw. you might consider using `GeneratedFromLogEvent` for the `${guid}` if writing to several targets. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Guid-layout-renderer